# which should I use for displaying details of an event -css or table

Tags: html, css, layout

In my web app,I have many instances of Event created by a user.If the user requests to view the details of a specific event ,it is shown as

```
Created By      : damon
Name            : myhomework
Creation date   : 24 October, 2012
Duraion         : 2 hours ,40 minutes
Status          : PENDING
Perc.completion : 40% (piechart image)
```

So,which is the correct way to create this layout.Is `<table>` the way to do this?Or should I use css? I tried to do this with css ,but it seems I am getting it all messed up when float is used.

Any suggestions welcome

Comment: CSS could obviously do this, but an HTML `table` element might work too. What are you asking?

Comment: A list of key/value pairs certainly qualifies as tabular data, so a table would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `DL` (definition list) here. Something like this:

HTML

```css
    dt { clear:left; float:left; width:8em; }
    dd { float:left; }
```

```html
    <dl>
        <dt>Created By:</dt>
        <dd>damon</dd>

        <dt>Name:</dt>
        <dd>myhomework</dd>
        
        <dt>Creation date:</dt>
        <dd>24 October, 2012</dd>

        <dt>Duraion:</dt>
        <dd>2 hours ,40 minutes</dd>
        
        <dt>Status:</dt>
        <dd>PENDING</dd>

        <dt>Perc.completion:</dt>
        <dd>40% (piechart image)</dd>
    </dl>
```

Although you could certainly make the case that a table is appropriate as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a Definition List `<dl>`-tag, as this can be used perfectly for key-value-pairs. To get your layout straight you could use this:

```css
dl {
    width:          400px;
}

dt {
    display:        inline-block;
    width:          100px;
    margin:         0;
    padding:        0;
}


dd {
    display:        inline-block;
    width:          290px;
    margin:         0;
    padding:        0;
}

dd:before {
    content:        ':';
    padding:        0 10px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<dl>
    <dt>Item 1</dt>
    <dd>Text 1</dd>

    <dt>Item 2</dt>
    <dd>Text 2</dd>

    <dt>Item 3</dt>
    <dd>Text 3</dd>
</dl>
```